# Solving variable value combination through Boolean expression

Tags: c#, boolean

I do have some boolean expressions in a file as mentioned below.

```
 ((a&&b)|(c&&a)|(r&&s) && !(c)&& (f>=5)) = false
 ((e&&f) !(n)&& p) = false
```

and so on.

My task is to find all the possible boolean combinations for the variables used in the expression , that would yield an outcome mentioned at the right hand side of the expression.

I am a beginner to c# .Kindly guide me achieve this.

Comment: so get a pencil and paper and start working it out....

Comment: To be fair this is more boolean logic than a programming question

Comment: @DavidPilkington agreed! OP: I'm not sure if I get the question, but do you mean you want all possible combinations of variables that will produce a true or a false? It seems very context-specific

Comment: Yes. I need all possible combinations that could produce the mentioned outcome. I need to implement a function in c# that could accomplish it.

Comment: I dont see how you can have `(f>=5)` as well as `(e&&f)`

Comment: That is just an example i gave.that variable f can be changed as "h" (h>=5)

Comment: For each line i need separate outcomes.i dont want to resolve these as 2 equations. Rather 1st line will have some set of variables and 2nd line will have other set of variables in it and so on. The output file should have possible combinations for first line(expression) and then for 2nd expression and so on.

Comment: Two words: Truth table

Comment: Are you trying to solve SAT? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it for a limited number of inputs, and know input values like this:

```
public void CalculateExpression(Expression<Func<bool, bool, int, bool>> expr){
    var compiledExpr = expr.Compile();

    for(var a = false; !a; !a)
      for(var b = false; !b; !b)
        for(var c = 0; c < 100; c)
          if(compiledExpr.Invoke(a,b,c))
            //Print or do whatever you want with that parameter combination
}

//Call with any of your login sentences
CalculateExpression((a,b,c) => (a|b)&&(c>5) == false);
```